# How to use a report from a view inside another view in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a form where I upload a file, and I generate a report out of it. The thing is, I would also like to make the report available for download, as an archive. I would like to somehow include the CSS and the JS ( that I inherit from my layout ) inside the report, but I don't really know how to go about this.
So far, I am not storing the file ( the report's being generated from ) on server side, I delete it after I'm done with it.

The only solution I could think of so far, was: from my archive generating view, use urllib to post to the form generating the report, save the response, and just rewrite the links to the stylesheet/JS files.

Is there a simpler way to go about this? Is there a way to keep some files on server side as long as the client's session lives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the HttpResponse in the view you use to show the generated report instead of posting with urllib. If you have something along the lines of

```
def report_view(request):
   ...
   return render_to_response(request,....)
```

Then use the response object to create an archive

```
def report_view(request):
   ...
   archive_link = "/some/nice/url/to/the/archive"
   response = render_to_response(request, ... { "archive-link" : archive_link})
   store_archive(response)
   return response

def store_archive(response):
     # here you will need to find css/js files etc
     # and bundle them in whatever type of archive you like
     # then temporarily store that archive so it can be accessed by the archive_link
     # you previously used in your view to allow for downloading

def report_archive_view(request):
     # serve the temporarily stored archive, then delete it if you like
```

You can find all you need to know about [HttpResponse in the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/).

Although this might work for you I doubt that is what you are really after, maybe what you are really looking for is to [generate a pdf report using ReportLab](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-pdf/)?

Comment: My report is HTML based. But your answer is interesting :)

Answer (score 0):

you could always keep the files, and have a cron job that deletes files whose session has expired

Comment: How do I know which sessions expired?

Comment: you'd have to store a reference to the session with your files